# Expression for negating every other odd number index

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

Is there a way to have an iterative expression that negates every other odd number index (starting from 3)?

Basically, I am trying to write a generative expression that will give me value, given index number in a sequence that alternates every other odd number and looks like this:

```
index   value 
0       0
1       0
2       0
3       1
4       0
5       -1
6       0
7       1
```

--

As mentioned by Gerry in comments, $\sin \frac{n \pi}{2}$ and/or $\cos \frac{n \pi}{2}$ work quite well for values where index $\geq$ 2 ... Effectively, my problem is solved, where I just use conditionals to check for index values before applying the nontrivial sinusoidal multiplier.

Might there be a closed-form way that doesn't involve conditionals to have the value be nonzero only when index $\geq$ N (where N in this case is 2) ?

Comment: The sequence $\cos n\pi/2$ goes $1,0,-1,0,1,0,-1,0,\dots$ for $n=0,1,2,3,\dots$. You can build something, starting with that, no?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been abandoned by OP.

Comment: Yes, I'm still here - Gerry your comment actually solved my problem... mea culpa and general rustiness, I completely forgot about sinusoidal functions O_o - thanks! :) ps - if you put it in answers, i can mark it as correct. 

corollary is if there is a closed form way to have the first 3 values as 0? currently i'm just evaluating for index > before applying the non-trivial sinusoidal multiplier

Comment: No one can post an answer, since your question was put on hold when you abandoned it. I'll vote to reopen, and we'll see what happens.

Comment: @ina, not sure if you're still around, but if you've decided to use Gerry's answer, you might find my entry function useful for avoiding conditionals. However, there's enough arithmetic ops in there that branching is probably cheaper-- if CPU cycles is what you're looking at.

Comment: Can I use the Kronecker delta? $\delta_{ij}$ is defined to mean $\begin{cases}0&\text{if }i\ne j\\1&\text{if }i=j\end{cases}$. Specifically, the function $\delta_{1x}$ might be useful.

Comment: Or I could just use $\dfrac{\lvert x-2\rvert-2\lvert x-1\rvert+\lvert x\rvert}2$ ([graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/13hfdip7nt)), which seems significantly less cheaty.

Answer (score 2):

Another method to express periodic behaviour are [quasi-polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-polynomial).  One way to define *quasi-polynomial* is *a polynomial in floor functions of linear terms*.

To get a function that is 1 exactly on each argument that is 3 modulo 4 use $$f: n\mapsto \left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{4}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{n}{4}\right\rfloor.$$
Here $\lfloor . \rfloor$ means round down to the next integer. Now you can subtract $$g: n\mapsto \left\lfloor\frac{n+3}{4}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{n+2}{4}\right\rfloor$$
which is 1 exactly if $n$ leaves remainder 1 mod 4.  This means that $$n\mapsto f(n)-g(n) = \left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{4}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{n}{4}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{n+3}{4}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{n+2}{4}\right\rfloor $$ gives the sequence $0,-1,0,1,0,-1,0,1,\dots$. There is no quasi-polynomial function that is non-zero at only one integer (you need one to fix the value at $n=1$), but there are non-polynomial ways to do that in the other answers.

Comment: This is very elegant. Makes my own version look hackish, which it is :)

Comment: Just one thing-- is there a way to compute $\lfloor . \rfloor$ without a conditional, as per the OP's requirement?

Comment: Yes and no. You can get rid of the floor functions if you accept the other definition of a quasi-polynomial: A polynomial with periodic coefficients. Then "periodic" can be implemented with modular arithmetic, so the conditionals are hidden there.

Comment: If conditionals are hidden by dropping bits to compute $\pmod{4}$, that's a lot cleaner & faster than sinusoids or $(-1)^{(...)}$, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in the comments, the sequence $\cos(n\pi/2)$ goes $1,0,-1,0,1,0,-1,0,\dots$ for $n=0,1,2,3,\dots$, so you can do the following: if $n=1$ then $0$, else $\cos((n-3)\pi/2)$.

Eliminating that glitch at $n=1$ is tricky. Basically, you want a function $f$ with $f(1)=1$, $f(n)=0$ for all $n\ne1$, so you can just use $\cos((n-3)\pi/2)+f(n)$. But I think the amount of effort you'd have to put in to construct such a function would be more than what you'd gain by not having to do the $n=1$ check.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fun question. Here's something that works if $n$ is restricted to be integer. It's undefined elsewhere. Gerry's trigonometric version has the advantage of accepting any real number. Also, this assumes you're allowing the silly absolute-value hack $\sqrt{n^2}$ and can compute $(-1)^{n}$.

$$\begin{align}
\text{Abs}(n) & = \sqrt{n^2} \\
\text{Min}(a,b) & = \frac{a + b - \text{Abs}(a - b)}{2} \\
\text{Max}(a,b) & = \frac{a + b + \text{Abs}(a - b)}{2} \\
\text{Entry}(n) & = \text{Min}(\text{Max}(0, n-2), 1) \\
\text{ZeroOne}(n) & = (1 - (-1)^n) / 2 \\
\text{LastEvenN}(n) & = n - \text{ZeroOne}(n) \\
\text{PairedAlt}(n) & = (-1)^{\text{LastEvenN}(n)/2\ +\ 1} \\
\end{align}$$

**This gives us the final formula:** $f(n) = \text{Entry}(n) \cdot \text{ZeroOne}(n) \cdot \text{PairedAlt}(n)$.

$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
n & \text{Entry($n$)} & \text{ZeroOne($n$)} & \text{LastEvenN($n$)} & \text{PairedAlt($n$)} & f(n) \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
3 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
4 & 1 & 0 & 4 & -1 & 0 \\
5 & 1 & 1 & 4 & -1 & -1 \\
6 & 1 & 0 & 6 & 1 & 0 \\
7 & 1 & 1 & 6 & 1 & 1 \\
8 & 1 & 0 & 8 & -1 & 0 \\
9 & 1 & 1 & 8 & -1 & -1 \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots
\end{array}$$

Comment: PairedAlt is very nice !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
 $$\frac14 \left(1 + (-1)^{2^{n(n-1)}}\right)
(1-(-1)^n) (-1)^{(n+1)(1-(-1)^n)/4} $$

The purpose of the factor $1 + (-1)^{2^{n(n-1)}}$ is to force the
value to be zero when $n = 1$. The value of $n(n-1)$ is zero for $0$ or $1$,
positive everywhere else, which means that for $0$ or $1$,
$2^{n(n-1)}=1$ and $1 + (-1)^{2^{n(n-1)}} = 0$,
but for any other integer, $2^{n(n-1)}$ is even and $1 + (-1)^{2^{n(n-1)}} = 0$.

In fact if you take any formula that gives you $0$ for every even $n$
and $(-1)^{(n-1)/2}$ for every odd $n$,
you can multiply it by $\frac12\left(1 + (-1)^{2^{n(n-1)}}\right)$
in order to force the formula to evaluate to $0$ for $n = 1$
without changing any of the other results.
So this would work:

$$\frac12\left(1 + (-1)^{2^{n(n-1)}}\right)
 \cos\left(\frac12 (n+1)\pi \right).$$

But personally, the following seems much simpler to me:

$$a_n = \begin{cases}
\phantom{-}0 & \text{if $n$ is even or $n < 3$,} \\
\phantom{-}1 & \text{if $n \equiv 3 \pmod 4$} \\
-1 & \text{if $n \equiv 1 \pmod 4$} \\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: The $(-1)^{2^{n(n-1)}}$ idea is very nice !

Answer (score 1):

As already noted, $\sin(\frac{\pi x}2)$ or $\cos(\frac{\pi x}2)$ work well, except for some isolated points near the beginning. However, the function $$f_n(x)=\frac{\sin \pi (x-n)}{\pi (x-n)}$$
for integer $n$ is equal to $1$ for $x=n$ and $0$ on the other integers. You can use this to cancel out the points where you would need conditionals otherwise. For example, your specific function can be represented as
$$a_n=f_1(n)-\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)=\frac{\sin \pi (n-1)}{\pi (n-1)}-\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use a step function that is $0$ for input less than $N$ and $1$ for input $\geq N$, and multiply this with the $-\sin\mathopen{}\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)\mathclose{}$.

Such a step function (assuming integer input) can be given by $$s_N(n)=\frac{\left\lvert n+1-N\right\rvert-\left\lvert n-N\right\rvert+1}{2}$$

So all together: $$f_N(n)=-\sin\mathopen{}\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)\mathclose{}\left(\frac{\left\lvert n+1-N\right\rvert-\left\lvert n-N\right\rvert+1}{2}\right)$$

[image: plot of function defined above]

---

Note: some may say that the absolute value function is secretly using a conditional. But you can either interpret $|x|$ as $\sqrt{x^2}$, or you can interpret $|x|$ as what you get when you replace the sign bit in a binary representation of $x$ in the computer's memory with the bit for positive.